# Choose 2 numbers from 100 numbers

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

If I want to choose a set of 2 positive integers less than 100, is that a permutation or a combination? I can't understand does the order matter in this case or it does not?

Comment: Note that you are choosing a *set* containing two positive integers less than $100$. Sets, in it of themselves, are unordered. Thus the order does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a combination, since the order of the 100 items doesn't matter.

The number of ways to choose $k$ out of $n$ is given by the binomial coefficient \begin{pmatrix}n \\ k \end{pmatrix}
which in your case would be $$\begin{pmatrix}100 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}=4950$$

*Edit: As amWhy points out below, it may be more appropriate to interpret OP's question as "2 out of 99 numbers". Either way, the formula holds.*

Comment: But there are only 99 numbers to choose from.  "positive numbers...**less than 100...** "

Comment: ...hence we have $$99\choose 2$$ as an answer.

Comment: @amWhy Hmm, yeah, but I went with what was in the title of the question - I guess it is a little ambiguous. I'll let my answer be as it is and refer to your comment. Thanks!

Comment: Understandable, @Lovsovs.;-)

Answer (score 1):

Informally, a permutation of a set is a rearrangement of all its elements. That is, a subset with two elements is not a permutation, simply because it has only two elements. I think that you are messing up permutations and variations.

A variation with $2$ elements is an *ordered* pair. So the variations $42,18$ and $18,42$ are different.

A combination with two elements is a set, or more precisely, a subset. Two subsets are the same if and only if they have the same elements, no mattter the order in which you write them. So the combinations $\{18,42\}$ and $\{42,18\}$ are one and the same.

So there are more variations than combinations.

To distinguish them, an useful but somewhat dangerous question is "Does the order matter?". A safer question is: "Choosing the same elements in two different orders, does it yield different results?"